# AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.
Izvorna datoteka: http://dostavahrane.si/ScriptResource.axd?d=OdsYNSuXxjlt8rcl-C-veHyjBYioAGFje3gsHih3su6oLU1jX125fdCipsztHIubjtFptWsSrTvzlMvPBfnnMGfz62_ByInZiFjjOCVmrpHz8bozy1q4kx6vPqQyelCTItLxGQ2&t=245582f9

i am using AjaxControlToolkit for .net 3.5 in VS 2008. Why i get this error. Must i downgrade it?

I downlaod it from here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1506194.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got such error once in one of my projects and since I didn't find a cause, I did what the exception message says - instead of ASP.NET ScriptMessage, I've put Toolkit's Script Manager on the page.

It probably is only a workaround but follow it if you won't find any other solution.